# autoit and koda: how does gui create knows which koda form to use?

Tags: autoit

I'm new to autoit, I wanted to create 2 forms and open the second one by clicking on a button of the first one.

Here are my forms in koda:

[image: koda1]

[image: koda2]

```
#include <ButtonConstants.au3>
#include <GUIConstantsEx.au3>
#include <StaticConstants.au3>
#include <WindowsConstants.au3>
#Region ### START Koda GUI section ### Form=
$Act = GUICreate("Activités et Compétences", 615, 441, 196, 125)
$RetourAccueil=1
$ETAPE = 1

$Label1 = GUICtrlCreateLabel(" Activités && Compétences", 41, 12, 558, 85)
GUICtrlSetFont(-1, 36, 800, 0, "My Lucky Penny")
$PPE = GUICtrlCreateButton("PPE", 48, 168, 75, 25)
$TP = GUICtrlCreateButton("TP", 152, 168, 75, 25)
$TD = GUICtrlCreateButton("TD", 256, 168, 75, 25)
$STAGE1 = GUICtrlCreateButton("STAGE 1", 368, 168, 75, 25)
$STAGE2 = GUICtrlCreateButton("STAGE 2", 480, 168, 75, 25)
$Group1 = GUICtrlCreateGroup("Activités", 24, 136, 561, 81)
GUICtrlCreateGroup("", -99, -99, 1, 1)
GUISetState(@SW_SHOW)


#EndRegion ### END Koda GUI section ###
Func RetourAccueil()

EndFunc
While 1
    $nMsg = GUIGetMsg()
    Switch $nMsg
        Case $GUI_EVENT_CLOSE
            Exit

        Case $PPE
            if $ETAPE=1 THEN
               GUICtrlSetData(-1, "|PPE2.1-Mission ADISPO|PPE -Installation PFSENSE|PPE-Cas Kaspersky|Autres")
            EndIf
         Case $TP
               $TP = GUICtrlCreateButton("NewName", 480, 168, 75, 25)
         Case $TD
                 $TD = GUICreate("Activités et Compétences", 615, 441, 196, 125)
               WinActivate($TDPAGE)
         Case $STAGE1
               MsgBox(64,'information','ok')
         Case $STAGE2

    EndSwitch
WEnd
```

And here is the result whn I run it:

[image]

By clicking on the button TD, I want to open the second form and close the first one but I have o idea how I tried with:

```
   Case $TD
            $TD = GUICreate("Activités et Compétences", 615, 441, 196, 125)
           WinActivate($TDPAGE)
```

But it didn't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you generate form code in KODA, it only generates code for the form you have currently selected, so you need to generate the code for the second form separately.

The reason your current code does not work is that new GUI's are invisible by default, and you need to make them visible by executing `GUISetState(@SW_SHOW)` after creating them (just like the code generated by KODA does for the first form).

If you want to close the first form, use `GUIDelete()`. If you look at AutoIt's documentation, you'll find that all GUI functions accept an optional parameter to specify which GUI you want to operate on, and if you don't specify it, it will use the last window you created (or operated on). As you want to specifically delete the first GUI, you either have to make sure you delete it before creating the second GUI, or explicitly specify the GUI you want to delete, i.e. `GUIDelete($Act)`.

Finally, you seem to have made a typo in writing `WinActivate($TDFORM)`. Did you mean to write `WinActivate($TD)`? Regardless, it should not be necessary to activate the form, as a newly created GUI will be activated automatically.